# How to remote debug .NET Core application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, remote-debugging

I can attach to my server because it is a long running application, but how to start .NET Core application (WPF). I've tried **Use Remote Computer** but that doesn't allow port only IP address. I can try to attach quickly but it is missing some start-up troubleshooting. I always publish client & server on a remote computer the files are up-to-date and server debugging is working via attaching.

Is there a way to run project like in a classic .NET Framework and remote debug?

Edit: Remote settings for a project looks like this:

[image: Remote debugging settings]

Comment: Look into pdb files. I vaguely remember there being a way to produce them and I think with that file you can debug the corresponding core application. Sorry it's vague, I don't remember enough to give a conclusive answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have pdb files generated, optimization is turned off. The breakpoints will hit OK, but only if I "attach to process" not by just running (F5) a project.

Comment: Like this covers? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-csharp?view=vs-2019

Comment: I've checked that out, but if you fill in Use Remote Computer for .NET Core project it is yellow (invalid) when you fill in port (default 4024 in my case), if you don't fill port (only IP address) it won't run either. You can't save it therefore you can't run it. The guide seems not to be actual.

Comment: I've added how it looks like. Compare it to the guide. It's obviously out of date.